# Display image using absolute path

Tags: php, html

I am using uploadify to upload img to server at the time of upload i saved absolute path to the data base its like:

`/var/www/html/workbench/photogallery/uploads/logo2.jpg`

now I want to display the same in browser the following method does not work

```
<div id="photos">
    <h3>Photo title</h3>
    <P class="like"><a href="#">Like</a> </P>
    <p class="date">date </p>
    <p class="pclear" />
    <div id="image">
      <img src="<?php echo $result_set['path']; ?>" />
    </div>
    <p class="about">about image goes here</p>
</div>
```

above code doesn't  work. when I edit the path manually to uploads/logo2.jpg it works perfectly

how can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Your server and client machine should be the same, are they?

Comment: Never __ever__ post an absolute path to the client. It's a large security risk. Use a path relative to the hostname, or just a relative path.

Comment: ye same . I can access the image in browser directly . path like this file:///var/www/html/workbench/photogallery/uploads/logo2.jpg

Comment: @Compiler: Well *you* can; but I very much doubt that every visitor of your page will have `/var/www/html/workbench/photogallery/uploads/logo2.jpg` on *their* computer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use an url, not a path.

This:

```
/var/www/html/workbench/photogallery/uploads/logo2.jpg
```

is a physical path, the address on that server where the image is found. You need to use an url available for your visitors. I guess that you have a name mapped to that server (something like localhost or www.example.com).

From the structure I guess that your url would be something like

```
http://www.example.com/photogallery/uploads/logo2.jpg
```

where **www.example.com** is the base url you are using to get to that application

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<img src="/photogallery/uploads/<?php echo basename($result_set['path']) ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works for me and keeps the location of the images hidden from the browser.

```
<img src='fake.php' style='max-width:90px;'/>
```

Create a file called fake.php as follows

```
<?php
$thePic = "/var/www/html/workbench/photogallery/uploads/logo2.jpg";
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($thePic); 
// Output image and free up the memory 
header("Content-type: image/jpeg"); 
imagejpeg($image); 
imagedestroy($image); 
?>
```

You can adjust the code in the fake.php file to retrieve the location of $thePic from posted data or database, etc.